# Rotate pygame screen

Tags: python, pygame

I want to rotate the screen of my pygame window by 90 degrees and am unable to find any function to do so. I tried p.transform.rotate() but i guess that is used for Images only. Any help would be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use [`pygame.transform.rotate()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate). [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) just generates a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) which is associated to the display.
However, `pygame.transform.rotate()` returns a new but rotated [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object. Therefore you must `blit` the surface back on the dispaly:

```py
window.blit(pygame.transform.rotate(window, 90), (0, 0))
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
text = font.render("Display", True, (255, 255, 0))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False          

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(text, text.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
    window.blit(pygame.transform.rotate(window, 90), (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```